# Doctrine exception "Data too long for column" when updating my schema

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

When I do a `app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`
I got this message :

```
$ app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
Updating database schema...


  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]                                                                                                                 
  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE recipes ADD has_video TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, CHANGE photo photo VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL':  
  SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'photo' at row 4268                                                          



  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]                                                               
  SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'photo' at row 4268  



  [PDOException]                                                                                    
  SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'photo' at row 4268  


doctrine:schema:update [--complete] [--dump-sql] [-f|--force] [--em [EM]]
```

So I tried to increase the size of my column in my entities :

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="photo", type="string", length=310, nullable=true)
 * @Expose
 * @Groups({"All", "GlobalStats"})
 */
private $photo;
```

I increase it to 310, but it still doesn't work.
Why can't I update my schema ?

Comment: What is the actual length of `photo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my type to `text`

```
 /**
     * @var text
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="photo", type="text", nullable=true)
     * @Expose
     * @Groups({"All", "GlobalStats"})
     */
    private $photo;
```

According to the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html): "Converts string data without a maximum length."

Answer (score 3):

You can find all the DBAL types [here in the Doctrine 2 documentation chapter: **8. Types**](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html).

For [string type](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#string) you find the following comment:

> Database vendors have different limits for the maximum length of a varying string. Doctrine internally maps the `string` type to the vendor’s `text` type if the maximum allowed length is exceeded. (...)

For MySQL this maximum is 255 characters but according to the docs it should use text when this value is exceeded. Maybe the length of your photo was more then 310 characters?

Setting the data type to `text` like you did works because according to the docs:

> Maps and converts string data without a maximum length. If you don’t know the maximum length of the data to be stored, you should consider using this type.

So it is a proper solution. 
Keep in mind that it might be more optimal (better for performance) if you define the length of your database columns.